# @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) starts only one method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to run a few methods after the Spring Boot project starts. I'm using `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` annotation above the methods I want ran after the project launches. But it's only starting for one method at a time. I want multiple methods started at once. Is that the expected behavior for `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)`?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding `@Async` also above the method? 
This listener is invoked synchronously. You can make it asynchronous by simply adding `@Async` annotation.

Comment: This was valuable for my situation. I had a long-running task that was kicked off by this @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) event and it was blocking the health check causing deployments to fail. Simply adding @Async made it non-blocking and the health check now passes! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can have the event listeners execute asynchronously by adding the following bean to your `@Configuration` class.

```
@Bean(name = "applicationEventMulticaster")
public ApplicationEventMulticaster simpleApplicationEventMulticaster() {
    SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster eventMulticaster =
      new SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster();
    
    eventMulticaster.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    return eventMulticaster;
}
```

If you've defined a custom `TaskExecutor` then you should replace `new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()` with `yourCustomTaskExecutorBeanMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

Its OK to place several (more than one) methods annotated with `@EventListener` all of them will be executed:

```
@Configuration
public class SampleConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SampleBean sampleBean() {return new SampleBean();}  

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationReadyEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }


    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationReadyEvent2(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("How are you");
    }

}
```

This will print both "Hello" and "How are you" upon the succesfull start of the Application Context.

Now, its true that spring doesn't invoke them concurrently, it resolves all the listeners and calls them sequentially.

If you need a parallel execution you can create one listener that will be an "entry point" for the logical tasks that must be run in parallel and use Threads / Thread Pool Executors to run the code of your choice in parallel

Answer (score 0):

I had run into a similar issue where ApplicationReadyEvent was annoted for 3 function but in debugging we found it to fire for only 1 always. We added @Order and kept that function with the highest index(i.e. lowest priority), as in our case it was running for an indefinite while loop, and found that all the 3 functions were invoked seamlessly.